# Geometry of Riemann Stieltjes integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> What is the geometrical interpretation of **Riemann Stieltjes Integration ?**

We know that for **Riemaan integration** $\int_{a}^b f(x)dx$ represents the area bounded by the curve $y=f(x)$& the straight lines $x=a$ & $x=b$.

But when we integrate $f(x)$ with respect to another function $g(x)$ then which area represents that integration geometrically ?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that instead of plotting the graphic of $f(x)$ "based" on the straight monodimensional line *Ox*, rising out of it along a second dimension *Oy*, you would instead plot it "based" on the possibly curvy bidimensional line $g(x)\in xOy$, rising out of it along a third dimension *Oz*, and forming a straight angle with the horizontal plane *xOy*.

Comment: For instance, if *g* would be a $($semi$)$circle, and *f* a constant, you'd get a cylindrical shape.

Comment: It is not clear to me..

Comment: @SayantanPanja: Take a sheet of paper, and draw on it the two axes of coordinates, and the graphic of a random function $g(x)$. Then imagine that from each point of the bidimensional plot of $g(x)$, a beam of light comes out of the sheet of paper, whose direction is perpendicular on that sheet of paper, and whose length is equal to the value of $f(x)$ in that point, $z=f(y)$, where $y=g(x)$. If the value is positive, then the beam of light goes upwards from the sheet; if not, then it goes downwards. You'll get a wavy surface, whose signed area is $\displaystyle\int fdg$.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the paper entitled

"A Geometric Interpretation of the Riemann-Stieltjes Integral"
American Mathematical Monthly  archive
Volume 95 Issue 5, May 1988 
 Pages 448-455

Comment: Please give the site.....

Comment: http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly/american-mathematical-monthly-table-contents